# Passing parent node in recursion

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, linq-to-xml

Is there any way to pass object (or reference) to a function, when that object is under 'construction' in recursion? I want to hold my parent node in his child.

Calling place in some method:

```
NavigationTreeNode node = FindNode(Resources.ShellView_TreeNodeBusinessRules);
var tmpList = LoadNodes(xDoc.Descendants("root").Elements("tab"), node);
```

And this is recursion:

```
 private List<NavigationTreeNode> LoadNodes(IEnumerable<XElement> nodes, NavigationTreeNode parentNode)
 {
     return nodes.Select(x => 
         new NavigationTreeNode(x.Attribute("display-name").Value, parentNode)
         { 
            TabName = x.Attribute("tab-name").Value,
            // Here I want to send object that is now under 
            // construction, or maybe reference
            ChildNodes = LoadNodes(x.Elements("tab"), /* ?? */)
         }).ToList();
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `{}` to specify the scope of the lambda expression and then you can save your new object to a variable, set its property and then return it:

```
return nodes.Select(x => 
{
    var obj = new NavigationTreeNode(x.Attribute("display-name").Value, parentNode)
    { 
        TabName = x.Attribute("tab-name").Value
    };
    obj.ChildNodes = LoadNodes(x.Elements("tab"), obj);
    return obj;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Amazing man, it works! I need more exercise with LINQ, definitely.
FYI, yes, that's just simple string.

Comment: @p__d - so tell me if this edit now is still correct for you

Comment: What breaks recursion here ?

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - haven't thought about it :) wasn't the question. But I assume that when an XElement has no "tab" elements then in the next call it will be `Select` on an empty list -> and will stop

Comment: @GiladGreen not at all, because I need that parameter. But it's compiling of course. Please, add that line also `obj.TabName = x.Attribute("tab-name").Value;` for others, if You find it appropriate, or just revert Your modification.

Comment: @Gilad Green sure thanks, my assumption is when `nodes` collection is empty, was little surprised as OP said it works without any issue, so this means no infinite loop

Comment: @MrinalKamboj empty element. Linq is responsible for that.

Comment: @p__d - reverted :)

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - I was also taken off guard for a moment with your comment but now we know the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Frankly this could be done better if you redesigned your navigation classes.  For this particular case, the structure doesn't lend itself well to using linq to rebuild it recursively.  While linq *can* be used to initialize recursive structures, it can't be utilized effectively when the structure is doubly linked.

And in general, it is wrong to be creating a list of the children to be used when initializing the your structure. It breaks encapsulation as you're providing direct access to an internal structure.  You should be providing methods to manipulate those anyway.

For instance with a structure like this, it would make things a lot easier:

```
class NavigationTreeNode
{
    private List<NavigationTreeNode> childNodes = new List<NavigationTreeNode>();
    public NavigationTreeNode(string tabName, string displayName)
    {
        TabName = tabName;
        DisplayName = displayName;
    }
    public NavigationTreeNode Parent { get; private set; }
    public string TabName { get; }
    public string DisplayName { get; }
    public IReadOnlyList<NavigationTreeNode> ChildNodes => childNodes.AsReadOnly();

    public void Add(NavigationTreeNode childNode)
    {
        if (childNode.Parent != null)
            childNode.Parent.Remove(childNode);
        childNodes.Add(childNode);
        childNode.Parent = this;
    }

    private void Remove(NavigationTreeNode childNode)
    {
        childNodes.Remove(childNode);
        childNode.Parent = null;
    }
}
```

Then the load function would look like this:

```
private NavigationTreeNode LoadNode(XElement node)
{
    var treeNode = new NavigationTreeNode((string)node.Attribute("tab-name"), (string)node.Attribute("display-name"));
    foreach (var tab in node.Elements("tab"))
        treeNode.Add(LoadNode(tab));
    return treeNode;
}
```

And depending on how far you want to go with the design, you can remove the need for the loop altogether and write it fully using linq. I'll leave that for you as an exercise.